# Redirect rule not fired in htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

Any thoughts why this url `example.com/hotelinfo.aspx?idhotel=2` is not redirecting to this one `example.com/new-url` using the following rule in my `.htaccess`?

```
Redirect 301 /hotelinfo.aspx?idhotel=2 http://www.example.com/new-url
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot match query string using `Redirect` directive, use `mod_rewrite` rules instead.

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^idhotel=2$
RewriteRule ^hotelinfo\.aspx$ http://www.example.com/new-url? [L,R=302,NC]
```

Once you verify it is working fine, replace `R=302` to `R=301`. Avoid using `R=301` (Permanent Redirect) while testing your mod_rewrite rules.